# Any performance differences between one large custom html tag or multiple individual tags in Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

We have about 8 asynchronous scripts that are being added by Google Tag Manager on every page. Currently these scripts are all in a single "Custom HTML" tag with a trigger of "All Pages".

Some of these scripts are not in the predefined standard list of gtm tags (chat, facebook, heatmap). Others are duplicates of standard gtm tags (google analytics, conversion tracking, remarketing). We have all these in a one "Custom HTML" tag.

Are there any performance impacts (or even gains) if we were to separate each script into it's own individual tag instead of having them all in a single "Custom HTML" tag? Any other factors to consider when making this decision? Control over tag firing priority perhaps?

We recently had a consultant review our gtm configuration and he initially didn't realise that we had all our tags in the one Custom HTML tag, hence the reason for this question. Separate tags would be clearer. However it just doesn't feel quite right to split this up into multiple tags.

For the purpose of this question, please assume that these tags will always need to be fired on every page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found this Information on an [official google website](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/2772488?hl=en) that maybe answers your question:

> Combine multiple similar tags with slightly different configurations
>   into a single tag that uses variables to dynamically set fields that
>   need to change. Example: Ten similar tags, each configured with a
>   trigger that tells each tag to fire on ten separate pages, can be
>   combined into one single tag/trigger combination that uses a Lookup
>   Table variable to set the values of the relevant fields.

On our companys website we also have several tags/action combined in one tag and it seems to work fine.

Comment: I hadn't seen that before. It would seem to indicate that they recommend fewer tags. However at the bottom it has _Replace custom tags with one of the supported tag templates. Use built-in tag templates instead of custom code whenever possible._

Comment: I think the recommendation to use the supported tag templates is for users who don't have a lot of programming knowledge. Also in case of customer support google and the official partners want to keep it as simple as possible, so they recommend a solution that they know how to handle instead of looking through custom code.